# Use static_cast on non-pointer POD instead of c style cast

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

is there any reason for using static_cast on non pointer POD data types, like int, float, double?

```
float v = 100;
int x = (int) v vs int x = static_cast<int>v
```

Is there any reason/advantage on using that, I saw several answers that covers pointers, but plain POD data I could not find explicit answers about non-pointers.

Comment: `(int)v` is c. `static_cast<int>(v)` is c++.

Comment: When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

Comment: C or C++. You cannot have both here.

Comment: @Walter fixed, removed C tag

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie, makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best reason I've heard is because you can grep for `static_cast` and know you will only find casts whereas `(int)` is much less specific about what's going on in that expression.

Also, C-style casts can remove or add `const` or `volatile` and change types without any warnings. If you try to `static_cast` a `const` pointer/reference type to a non-`const` pointer/reference type, you will get a compile error.